# Chainlink v0.8 Smart Contract Deployment Issue

Tags: ethereum, chainlink

I am having issues verifying my smart contract on Rinkeby Testnet using @chainlink. My contract is deploying to Rinkeby fine but runs into issues when I have publish_source on. The contract verifies fine when using v0.6 and Solidity 0.6.6, I seem to only have issues with v0.8. Anyone know why this might be happening?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

/**
 * @title MyContract is an example contract which requests data from
 * the Chainlink network
 * @dev This contract is designed to work on multiple networks, including
 * local test networks
 */
contract MyContract is ChainlinkClient, ERC721 {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

    address constant RINKEBY_ORACLE =
        0x3A56aE4a2831C3d3514b5D7Af5578E45eBDb7a40;
    bytes32 constant RINKEBY_JOB_ID =
        bytes32("187bb80e5ee74a139734cac7475f3c6e");

    uint256 constant FEE = 0.1 * 10**18;

    uint256 public tokenCounter;

    bytes32 public data;
    string public image_url;

    struct Clip {
        string name;
        string url;
    }

    Clip[] public clips;

    mapping(bytes32 => string) public requestIdToClipName;
    mapping(bytes32 => address) public requestIdToSender;
    mapping(bytes32 => string) public requestIdToTokenURI;
    event requestedCollectible(bytes32 indexed requestId);

    mapping(bytes32 => uint256) public requestToTokenId;
    mapping(uint256 => string) public tokenIdToName;
    mapping(uint256 => string) public tokenIdToImgUrl;

    constructor(address _link) public ERC721("Tests", "TST") {
        if (_link == address(0)) {
            setPublicChainlinkToken();
        } else {
            setChainlinkToken(_link);
        }
        setChainlinkOracle(0x3A56aE4a2831C3d3514b5D7Af5578E45eBDb7a40);
        tokenCounter = 0;
    }

    function getChainlinkToken() public view returns (address) {
        return chainlinkTokenAddress();
    }

    function createRequestTo(
        string memory _url,
        string memory _path,
        string memory clipName
    ) public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(
            RINKEBY_JOB_ID,
            address(this),
            this.fulfill.selector
        );
        req.add("get", _url);
        req.add("path", _path);

        requestId = sendChainlinkRequestTo(RINKEBY_ORACLE, req, FEE);
        requestIdToClipName[requestId] = clipName;
        requestIdToSender[requestId] = msg.sender;
        emit requestedCollectible(requestId);
        return requestId;
    }

    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, bytes32 _data)
        public
        recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        address nftOwner = requestIdToSender[_requestId];
        string memory name = requestIdToClipName[_requestId];
        uint256 newItemId = clips.length;

        data = _data;
        image_url = bytes32ToString(data);

        clips.push(Clip(name, image_url));

        _safeMint(nftOwner, newItemId);

        tokenIdToName[newItemId] = name;
        tokenIdToImgUrl[newItemId] = image_url;
    }

    function getNumberOfClips() public view returns (uint256) {
        return clips.length;
    }

    /**
     * @notice Allows the owner to withdraw any LINK balance on the contract
     */
    function withdrawLink() public {
        LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
        require(
            link.transfer(msg.sender, link.balanceOf(address(this))),
            "Unable to transfer"
        );
    }

    /**
     * @notice Call this method if no response is received within 5 minutes
     * @param _requestId The ID that was generated for the request to cancel
     * @param _payment The payment specified for the request to cancel
     * @param _callbackFunctionId The bytes4 callback function ID specified for
     * the request to cancel
     * @param _expiration The expiration generated for the request to cancel
     */
    function cancelRequest(
        bytes32 _requestId,
        uint256 _payment,
        bytes4 _callbackFunctionId,
        uint256 _expiration
    ) public {
        cancelChainlinkRequest(
            _requestId,
            _payment,
            _callbackFunctionId,
            _expiration
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the script I am using to deploy:

```
from brownie import MyContract, accounts, network, config
from scripts.helpful_scripts import fund_contract


def main():
    dev = accounts.add(config['wallets']['from_key'])
    print(network.show_active())

    publish_source = True

    my_contract = MyContract.deploy(
        config['networks'][network.show_active()]['link_token'],
        {"from": dev},
        publish_source=publish_source
    )
    fund_contract(my_contract)
    return my_contract
```

This is the error:

```
Transaction sent: 0x01ef409a5b0c2f6de60194f14f1d2e8ffac9a6ce6397aaa38392d949e2656909
  Gas price: 1.000000008 gwei   Gas limit: 2793499   Nonce: 359
  MyContract.constructor confirmed   Block: 9332417   Gas used: 2539545 (90.91%)
  MyContract deployed at: 0x42fBa06808C3cB11e5D7AcC6BB02B1A612e040d1

  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 49, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 103, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "./scripts/deploy_api.py", line 11, in main
    my_contract = MyContract.deploy(
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 600, in __call__
    return tx["from"].deploy(
  File "brownie/network/account.py", line 555, in deploy
    contract.publish_source(deployed_contract, silent=silent)
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 410, in publish_source
    contract_info = self.get_verification_info()
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 292, in get_verification_info
    if symbol_alias["local"] is not None:
KeyError: 'local'
```

Answer (score 0):

Two points going on here:

1. Brownie Etherscan verification doesn't work well with Solidity v0.8. Work is being done to fix this issue.
2. Looks like you are deploying to a local network instead of Rinkeby. Either remove publish_source when deploying locally or add `--network rinkeby` to the end of your deploy script to deploy to Rinkeby.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on the kovan network using Solidity v0.8. Is there a resolution?